# Generate codes including unquote-splice by a loop in Common Lisp

Tags: macros, common-lisp, backquote

I'm writing a macro to generate codes used by another macro in Common Lisp. But I'm new at this and have difficulty in constructing a macro that takes in a list `(bar1 bar2 ... barn)` and produces the following codes by a loop.

```
`(foo
   ,@bar1
   ,@bar2
     ...
   ,@barn)
```

I wonder whether this can be achieved not involving implement-dependent words such as `SB-IMPL::UNQUOTE-SPLICE` in sbcl.

Maybe I didn't give a clear description about my problem. In fact I want to write a macro `gen-case` such that

```
(gen-case
  (simple-array simple-vector)
  ('(dotimes ($1 $5)
      (when (and (= (aref $4 $2 $1) 1) (zerop (aref $3 $1)))
        $0))
   '(dolist ($1 (aref $4 $2))
      (when (zerop (aref $3 $1))
        $0)))
  objname body)
```

produces something like

```
`(case (car (type-of ,objname))
   (simple-array
     ,@(progn
         (setf temp
               '(dotimes ($1 $5)
                  (when (and (= (aref $4 $2 $1) 1) (zerop (aref $3 $1)))
                    $0)))
         (code-gen body)))
   (simple-vector
     ,@(progn
         (setf temp
               '(dolist ($1 (aref $4 $2))
                  (when (zerop (aref $3 $1))
                    $0)))
         (code-gen body))))
```

In general cases, the lists taken in by `gen-case` may contain more than two items.
I have tried

```
``(case (car (type-of ,,objname))
    ,',@(#|Some codes that produce target codes|#))
```

but the target codes are inserted to the `quote` block and thus throw an exception in the macro who calls the macro `gen-case`. Moreover, I have no way to insert `,@` to the target codes as a straightforward insertion will cause a "comma not inside a backquote" exception.

The codes generated are part of another macro

```
(defmacro DSI-Layer ((obj-name tag-name) &body body)
  "Data Structure Independent Layer."
  (let ((temp))
    (defun code-gen (c)
      (if (atom c) c
        (if (eq (car c) tag-name)
          (let ((args (cadr c)) (codes (code-gen (cddr c))) (flag nil))
            (defun gen-code (c)
              (if (atom c) c
                (if (eq (car c) *arg*)
                  (let ((n (cadr c)))
                    (if (zerop n) (progn (setf flag t) codes)
                      (nth (1- n) args)))
                  (let ((h (gen-code (car c))))
                    (if flag
                      (progn
                        (setf flag nil)
                        (append h (gen-code (cdr c))))
                      (cons h (gen-code (cdr c))))))))
            (gen-code temp))
          (cons (code-gen (car c)) (code-gen (cdr c))))))
    `(case (car (type-of ,obj-name))
       (simple-array
         ,@(progn
             (setf temp
               '(dotimes ($1 $5)
                   (when (and (= (aref $4 $2 $1) 1) (zerop (aref $3 $1)))
                     $0)))
             (code-gen body)))
       (simple-vector
         ,@(progn
             (setf temp
               '(dolist ($1 (aref $4 $2))
                  (when (zerop (aref $3 $1))
                    $0)))
             (code-gen body))))))
```

and I've set up a read-macro

```
(defvar *arg* (make-symbol "ARG")) 
(set-macro-character #\$
  #'(lambda (stream char)
      (declare (ignore char))
      (list *arg* (read stream t nil t))))
```

The intention of `DSI-Layer` is to add a piece of code to determine the type of input parameters. For example, the codes

```
(defun BFS (G v)
  (let* ((n (car (array-dimensions G)))
         (visited (make-array n :initial-element 0))
         (queue (list v))
         (vl nil))
    (incf (aref visited v))
    (DSI-Layer (G next-vertex)
      (do nil ((null queue) nil)
        (setf v (pop queue)) (push v vl)
        (next-vertex (i v visited G n)
          (setf queue (nconc queue (list i)))
          (incf (aref visited i)))))
    vl))
```

will be converted to

```
(defun BFS (G v)
  (let* ((n (car (array-dimensions G)))
         (visited (make-array n :initial-element 0))
         (queue (list v))
         (vl nil))
    (incf (aref visited v))
    (case (car (type-of G))
      (simple-array
       (do nil ((null queue) nil)
         (setf v (pop queue))
         (push v vl)
         (dotimes (i n)
           (when (and (= (aref G v i) 1) (zerop (aref visited i)))
             (setf queue (nconc queue (list i)))
             (incf (aref visited i))))))
      (simple-vector
       (do nil ((null queue) nil)
         (setf v (pop queue))
         (push v vl)
         (dolist (i (aref G v))
           (when (zerop (aref visited i))
             (setf queue (nconc queue (list i)))
             (incf (aref visited i)))))))))
```

Now I just wonder that whether the `DSI-Layer` can be generated from another macro `gen-case` by passing the type names and corresponding code templates to it or not.

By the way, I don't think the specific meaning of generated codes matters in my problem. They are just treated as data.

Comment: `,@b1 ... ,@bn` is the same as `,@(append b1 ... bn)`, if you want to have a look at a macro used in macros, have a look at `once-only`: https://malisper.me/once-only/

Comment: I am entirely confused by your macro.  What's `temp`?  Does `code-gen` use it free?  If so, why not just pass it as an argument?  Why are things quoted in the macro form?  I think this is an XY problem: the problem is that the macro design is confused (or looks confused to me).  What problem, semantically, are you actually trying to solve with this macro?

Answer (score 1):

Don't be tempted to use internal details of backquote.  If you have the lists you want to append in distinct variables, simply append them:

```
`(foo
  ,@(append b1 b2 ... bn))
```

If you have a list of them in some single variable (for instance if they've come from an `&rest` or `&body` argument) then do something like

```
`(foo
  ,@(loop for b in bs
          appending b))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem - you need it not for a function call
but for a macro-call with `case`.

One cannot use dynamically macros - in a safe way.
One has to use `eval` but it is not safe for scoping.

@tfb as well as me answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104586/generate-typecase-with-macro-in-common-lisp) for `type-case`
lengthily.

#### previous answer (wrong for this case)

No need for a macro.

```
`(foo
   ,@bar1
   ,@bar2
     ...
   ,@barn)
```

with evaluation of its result
by pure functions would be:

```
(apply foo (loop for bar in '(bar1 bar2 ... barn)
            nconc bar))
```

`nconc` or `nconcing` instead of `collect` fuses lists together and is very useful in `loop`. - Ah I see my previous answerer used `append` btw `appending` - `nconc` `nconcing` however is the "destructive" form of "append". Since the local variable `bar` is destructed here which we don't need outside of the `loop` form, using the "destructive" form is safe here - and comes with a performance advantage (less elements are copied than when using `append`). That is why I wired my brain always to use `nconc` instead of `append` inside a `loop`.

Of course, if you want to get the code construct, one could do

```
`(foo ,@(loop for bar in list-of-lists
              nconc bar))
```

Try it out:

```
`(foo ,@(loop for bar in '((1 2 3) (a b c) (:a :b :c)) nconc bar))
;; => (FOO 1 2 3 A B C :A :B :C)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers of all of you inspired me, and I came up with a solution to my problem. The macro

```
(defmacro Layer-Generator (obj-name tag-name callback body)
  (let ((temp (gensym)) (code-gen (gensym)))
    `(let ((,temp))
       (defun ,code-gen (c)
         (if (atom c) c
           (if (eq (car c) ,tag-name)
             (let ((args (cadr c)) (codes (,code-gen (cddr c))) (flag nil))
               (defun gen-code (c)
                 (if (atom c) c
                   (if (eq (car c) *arg*)
                     (let ((n (cadr c)))
                       (if (zerop n) (progn (setf flag t) codes)
                         (nth (1- n) args)))
                     (let ((h (gen-code (car c))))
                       (if flag
                         (progn
                           (setf flag nil)
                           (append h (gen-code (cdr c))))
                         (cons h (gen-code (cdr c))))))))
               (gen-code ,temp))
             (cons (,code-gen (car c)) (,code-gen (cdr c))))))
       (list 'case `(car (type-of ,,obj-name))
         ,@(let ((codes nil))
             (dolist (item callback)
               (push
                 `(cons ',(car item)
                    (progn
                      (setf ,temp ,(cadr item))
                      (,code-gen ,body)))
                 codes))
             (nreverse codes))))))
```

produces codes which are not the same as `DSI-Layer` but produce codes coincident with what the latter produces. Because the codes

```
`(case (car (type-of ,obj-name))
   (tag1
     ,@(#|codes1|#))
   (tag2
     ,@(#|codes2|#))
    ...)
```

are equivalent to

```
(list 'case `(car (type-of ,obj-name))
  (cons 'tag1 (#|codes1|#))
  (cons 'tag2 (#|codes2|#))
   ...)
```

And now we can use a loop to generate it just as what the `Layer-Generator` does.